# how do I avoid the infinite loop when using the paramiko port forward demo?

Tags: python, multithreading, infinite-loop, paramiko, portforwarding

I need use port forwarding in Python to communicate with a remote MySQL DB through an SSH tunnel. I downloaded the paramiko package and tried out the port forwarding demo (forward.py). It works very nicely, but I am having trouble integrating it into my own scripts (similar to the one below). When the main forwarding function is called it enters an infinite loop and the rest of my code does not execute. How can I use the forward.py demo and get past the infinite loop?

My script:

```
import paramiko
import forward
import MySQLdb
import cfg
import sys

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())

try:
    client.connect(cfg.remhost, cfg.remport, username=cfg.user, password=cfg.password)
except Exception, e:
    print '*** Failed to connect to %s:%d: %r' % (cfg.remhost, cfg.remport, e)
    sys.exit(1)


try:
    forward.forward_tunnel(3306, cfg.remhost, 3306, client.get_transport())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'C-c: Port forwarding stopped.'
    sys.exit(0)

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect('127.0.0.1', cfg.dbuser, cfg.dbpass, cfg.dbname)
except Exception, e:
    print 'Failed to connect to database'
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    cursor = self.db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM  ' + cfg.dbtable
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print str(len(results))
except Exception, e:
    print 'Failed to query database'
    sys.exit(1)
```

Here is the main chunk of the forward.py demo code:

```
class ForwardServer (SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
    allow_reuse_address = True


class Handler (SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        try:
            chan = self.ssh_transport.open_channel('direct-tcpip',
                                                   (self.chain_host, self.chain_port),
                                                   self.request.getpeername())
        except Exception, e:
            verbose('Incoming request to %s:%d failed: %s' % (self.chain_host,
                                                              self.chain_port,
                                                              repr(e)))
            return
        if chan is None:
            verbose('Incoming request to %s:%d was rejected by the SSH server.' %
                    (self.chain_host, self.chain_port))
            return

        verbose('Connected!  Tunnel open %r -> %r -> %r' % (self.request.getpeername(),
                                                            chan.getpeername(), (self.chain_host, self.chain_port)))
        while True:
            r, w, x = select.select([self.request, chan], [], [])
            if self.request in r:
                data = self.request.recv(1024)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    break
                chan.send(data)
            if chan in r:
                data = chan.recv(1024)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    break
                self.request.send(data)
        chan.close()
        self.request.close()
        verbose('Tunnel closed from %r' % (self.request.getpeername(),))


def forward_tunnel(local_port, remote_host, remote_port, transport):
    # this is a little convoluted, but lets me configure things for the Handler
    # object.  (SocketServer doesn't give Handlers any way to access the outer
    # server normally.)
    class SubHander (Handler):
        chain_host = remote_host
        chain_port = remote_port
        ssh_transport = transport
    ForwardServer(('', local_port), SubHander).serve_forever()


def verbose(s):
    if g_verbose:
        print s
```

Comment: OK, since nobody seems to want to answer this question, my new questions are: What about my original question is off-putting to everyone else? What should I change so that people will actually respond? Do I need to rephrase it or add more information?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the handler forward code to run in its own thread and use queues to communicate to it.

Or pull out the relevant calls and stuff it is in your own loop.  Hmmm, I am not sure how this works exactly.

Do you want your mysql calls to work with it in your program or forward from a different program?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looks like I need to learn how to run threads in Python. I do not need the forwarding script to be a part of my database script, and they do not really need to communicate with each other. The DB calls are sent to 127.0.0.1:3306 which the forwarding script is already forwarding to the remote server. I'm just surprised that I cannot find an example of this already posted somewhere.

Comment: I tried doing this and could not get it to work.  It was because my web host rejects port forwarding.  I tried doing this by writing my own app that gets run on the remote host after I create an SSH connection, but could not get it to work.  I did get some text through, but it could not handshake with the mysql server properly.  Sorry I can't be more help as I stopped messing with the Paramiko stuff when I realized my web host is a shared host and blocks port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

I am the upstream author of a Pyhon module called Python X2Go that heavily uses Paramiko for SSH session management.

Please take a look at the forward.py file in the code:
http://code.x2go.org/gitweb?p=python-x2go.git;a=blob;f=x2go/forward.py

The code of Python X2Go heavily uses Python gevent for server-client communication, port forwarding etc.

Greets,
Mike

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read our [faq]. [Please do not post answers that are just a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer): include useful content in your post, and provide the link for reference. Here, could you include some code (10–20 lines would be great) that demonstrate port forwarding?